# Is rhyming of two words a transitive property?

Tags: rhymes

Let's suppose A rhymes with B and B rhymes with C. Does A always rhyme with C?

Comment: First, I believe "transitional" should be "transitive". Second, I believe the answer is "yes", if include only "true" rhyme, that is, omit "forced" rhyme, such as rhyming "n" and "m", which is done a lot.

Comment: @HexagonTiling: good one! What were I thinking..

Comment: Well ... *Lord* rhymes with *fraud* in England, and *fraud* rhymes with *nod* in California.

Comment: @Hexagon Yes, many rhymes are just "close", not "exact". It's not really like a mathematical "equals" operation, but more like "approximately equal". So just as you could say that 1.00 ~= 1.01 and 1.01 ~= 1.02, after a long enough chain you could end up with something quite different from what you started with.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Except in the technical case of *equivocal words* (where a single word has multiple pronunciations).  If B was an equivocal word, it could rhyme with both A and C, yet A and C would not rhyme.  For example:

A = taxes
B = axes
C = taxis

In this case, B is the plural of *axe* to rhyme with A, and the plural of *axis* to rhyme with C, but A and C do not rhyme.

(Some might argue that this shouldn't count, because B is really two words, not one.  Fair enough; I did mention this counterexample was a technicality that breaks the transitive property of rhyming.  I still felt it was worth a mention.)

**EDIT**.  Since I've been called on my counterexample in the comments below, I offer one more example to mull over:

A = dollop  \ˈdä-ləp\
B = scallop  \ˈskä-ləp, ˈska-ləp\
C = gallop  \ˈga-ləp\

Most dictionaries list *two* pronunciations for scallop; one rhymes with A (dollop), the other rhymes with C (gallop).

Now, B isn't technically two words, but one - albeit with two pronunciations.  Still, A rhymes with B, and B rhymes with C, but A doesn't rhyme with C.

So, as the O.P. asked, "Does A *always* rhyme with C?"

Comment: Thanks. I was skeptical about the transitiviness and thought there must be a clear counterexample lying there. Well, this is one even if a bit technical.

Comment: I don't feel this is a counterexample.  As JR himself/herself has said, "axes" (more than one axe) and "axes" (more than one axis) are two different words.

Comment: @progo: I agree with David Wallace that this is not a counterexample. I agree with the answer that he gave. However, I can't refrain from telling an old joke that hedges one's bets: "If A = B, and B = C, then A = C, except where void or prohibited by law."

Comment: @DavidWallace: if that's your qualm, we can fix it (see edit).

Comment: Wow, that's a good edit.  I hadn't even thought of that particular case.  I guess rhyming isn't transitive after all.  I would hypothesise that in any one person's idiolect, rhyming is transitive; although I suspect that if I do, someone will come along and say "well, sometimes I pronounce neither with an EE sound, and sometimes I pronounce neither with an EYE sound, so it's not true in my idiolect".  Maybe I should delete my original answer.

Comment: @DavidWallace: I wouldn't delete your original post; it's all part of an intelligent conversation.  My initial thought was the same as yours: "Of course rhyming is transitive – what a silly question!" But then I gave it some extra thought... blame it on some really good math instructors I've had through the years.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.  "A rhymes with B" is a relationship of sameness; that is, a certain part of A is the same as the corresponding part of B.  The mathematical term for this is an "equivalence relation", which is always **reflexive** (everything rhymes with itself), **symmetric** (if A rhymes with B, then B rhymes with A) and **transitive**.

Comment: Yes, something I was thinking of. But there are more than enough ambiquities and other examples that I'm not sure if the transitiviness holds trivially.

Comment: Ambiquities ... sort of like iniquities?

Answer (score 4):

If you're talking about [perfect rhyme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_rhyme), the answer is *no*. The pair *obtain* and *remain* are a perfect rhyme, as are *retain* and *remain*, but *obtain* and *retain* do not form a perfect rhyme, since they both end with *-tain*, and the vowels before *-tain* are different. If you want rhymes to be transitive, you have to allow *identical rhymes* (see link above) and say that a word rhymes with itself.